# what's the difference between targes nodes and fetch nodes in tensorflow?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, tensorflow

In tensorflow, there is a function used to ReWrite the original graph(ReWriteGraphForExecution):

```
Status RewriteGraphForExecution(
    Graph* g, const gtl::ArraySlice<string>& fed_outputs,
    const gtl::ArraySlice<string>& fetch_outputs,
    const gtl::ArraySlice<string>& target_node_names,
    const DeviceAttributes& device_info) {
```

the above code is coming from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.0.0/tensorflow/core/graph/subgraph.cc#L229)
I am confused that the exact difference between fetch_outputs and target_node_names.

Thanks very much, any information will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This graphp may help you.

[image]

And here is the header declaration，

```
// Rewrite the graph structure of "*g" to deal with feeding node
// outputs, fetching node outputs, and only running a subset of the
// graph.  "fed_outputs" and "fetch_outputs" are both lists of
// output tensor identifiers in the form of
// "<name>[:<optional_output_index>]", and "target_nodes_str" is a
// lists of target node names in "*g" "g".
//
// In the resulting graph "*g", output edges in "fed_outputs" have
// been redirected to special "_recv" nodes introduced into the graph.
// If these fed nodes are not needed in order to compute the effects
// of the nodes in "targets_nodes" and "fetch_outputs", then these may
// be omitted from the graph.
//
// In the resulting graph "*g", additional "_send" nodes are connected
// to every output in "fetch_outputs".  These "_send" nodes are set up
// to execute on the device described by device_info.
//
// On success, returns OK, and sets "*g" to a version of "*g"
// that represents the portions of the graph necessary for producing
// the output of all nodes listed in "target_node_names" and fetching the
// specific node outputs specified in "fetch_outputs".
//
// On failure, returns the error status. Possible errors include:
//    - fed output "node:output_index" does not exist in "*g"
//    - fetch output "node:output_index" does not exist in "*g"
//    - target node "node" does not exist in "*g"
Status RewriteGraphForExecution(
    Graph* g, const gtl::ArraySlice<string>& fed_outputs,
    const gtl::ArraySlice<string>& fetch_outputs,
    const gtl::ArraySlice<string>& target_node_names,
const DeviceAttributes& device_info);
```

Comment: I have watched the graph, but it does display the target node,
and the comment from the source code is not easy for me to understand what is target node.

Comment: Some more clarification on this would help. I didn't find the answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the comment in this part of tensorflow source code would help

```
message CallableOptions {
  // Tensors to be fed in the callable. Each feed is the name of a tensor.
  repeated string feed = 1;

  // Fetches. A list of tensor names. The caller of the callable expects a
  // tensor to be returned for each fetch[i] (see RunStepResponse.tensor). The
  // order of specified fetches does not change the execution order.
  repeated string fetch = 2;

  // Target Nodes. A list of node names. The named nodes will be run by the
  // callable but their outputs will not be returned.
  repeated string target = 3;

  ...
}
```